# After a PC freeze (Windows 7) and disk integrity check, most data from PostgreSQL table was deleted

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

My development server is on a PC, using 64-bit Windows 7.  My PC has been randomly freezing on me lately, requiring a hard reboot (holding down power button until PC turns off)

Yesterday, as I was adding some data into my development server's database.  My PC froze again.  While I was turning the PC on again, Windows asked to check my disk integrity during the booting process.  During the check-up, a bunch of corrupted files were deleted.  After the check-up is complete, I started up my development server which asked me to reindex a table.  I did the re-indexing, and realized that my database of over 2 million rows now has only 12 thousand!

I'm guessing the PC freeze corrupted my table, and during the disk integrity check, Windows deleted all those data?  Is there some way for me to retrieve the lost data?

Comment: Have you tried to restore last backup?

Comment: I'd be concerned that the system instability and the disk integrity issues are related. You may want to check to see if you have hardware issues there. As for retrieving data, your best bet is probably reverting to backup.